# except IOError as e: using python 3 but shows invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x

I edit the code, it seems not the error of mising 'try':

```
def load_letter(folder, min_num_images):
image_files = os.listdir(folder)
dataset = np.ndarray(shape=(len(image_files), image_size, image_size),
                     dtype=np.float32)
print(folder)
num_images = 0
for image in image_files:
    image_file = os.path.join(folder, image)
    try:
        image_data = (ndimage.imread(image_file).astype(float) - 
                pixel_depth / 2) / pixel_depth

        if image_data.shape != (image_size, image_size):
            raise Exception('Unexpected image shape: %s' % str(image_data.shape))
        dataset[num_images, :, :] = image_data
        num_images = num_images + 1

    except IOError as e:
        print('Could not read:', image_file, ':', e, '- it\'s ok, skipping.')
dataset = dataset[0:num_images, :, :]
```

and I'm using python 3 not python 2 but it shows this error:

```
except Exception as e:
     ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I don't understand why since I'm using py3

Comment: `except` can't be used on its own: it can only be part of a `try` block.  Either the `try` is missing, or it isn't at the same indentation level as the `except`.

Comment: This isn't an MVCE because it isn't complete.

Comment: Thx for the comments, I have the 'try' part in my code... so i guess it is not the try that cause the error